# Arel Table with PostgreSQL OVERLAPS method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

Let me preface this by acknowledging that there are a couple of different ways to accomplish overlapping, but with regard to this question, I'm specifically trying to figure out how to use the actual `PostgreSQL OVERLAPS` method with `Arel`. To that end, this question has more to do with gaining a better understanding of Arel rather than implementing some version of overlapping functionality.

I'm using `Rails 5.1`

This is the SQL statement that I am trying to duplicate in Arel:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  venues.id
FROM
  venues
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  reservations
ON
  venues.id = reservations.venue_id
WHERE (
  (reservations.venue_id IS NULL)
  OR NOT (
    (reservations.start, reservations.end)
    OVERLAPS
    (DATE '2018-09-02', DATE '2018-09-03')
  )
)
```

I currently have the following which does generate the above:

```
Venue.arel_table.project(
  Venue.arel_table[:id]
).from(
  Venue.arel_table
).join(
  Reservation.arel_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
).on(
  Venue.arel_table[:id].eq(Reservation.arel_table[:venue_id])
).where(
 Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    Reservation.arel_table[:venue_id].eq(nil)
  ).or(
    Arel.sql("NOT ((reservations.start, reservations.end) OVERLAPS (DATE '2018-09-02', DATE '2018-09-03'))")
  )
)
```

However, I feel like there is probably a better way to do this; I had been trying to implement `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction` for `OVERLAPS` however, when I replace the above `Arel.sql` statement with the following, it doesn't execute the SQL properly:

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
  'OVERLAPS',
  [
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('(reservations.start, reservations.end)'),
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("(DATE '2018-09-02', DATE '2018-09-03')")
  ]
)
```

**results in**

```
...OVERLAPS ((reservations.start, reservations.end), (DATE '2018-09-02', DATE '2018-09-03'))
```

What is the proper method for implementing `OVERLAPS` with `Arel`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `OVERLAPS` is a SQL operator, I believe the following expression should work:

```
Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(
  'OVERLAPS', 
  Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('(reservations.start, reservations.end)'),
  Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("(DATE '2018-09-02', DATE '2018-09-03')"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rails7 you can use
`Arel::Nodes::Overlaps.new(left, right)`

Shorter version of answer:

```rb
Arel::Nodes::Overlaps.new(
  Arel.sql('(reservations.start, reservations.end)'),
  Arel.sql("(DATE '2018-09-02', DATE '2018-09-03')"
)
```

But saying A, why dont u say B? Here is clearly Arel soultion.

```rb
Arel::Nodes::Overlaps.new(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('', [Reservation.arel_table[:start], Reservation.arel_table[:end]]),
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('', [
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('::', Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('2018-09-02'), Arel.sql('DATE')),
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('::', Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('2018-09-03'), Arel.sql('DATE'))
  ])
)
```

Result of #to_sql is so damn good

```
("reservations"."start", "reservations"."end") && ('2018-09-02' :: DATE, '2018-09-03' :: DATE)
```

We can shorten it by using #overlaps method of Arel::Predications

```rb
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('', [Reservation.arel_table[:start], Reservation.arel_table[:end]]).overlaps(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('', [
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('::', Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('2018-09-02'), Arel.sql('DATE')),
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('::', Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('2018-09-03'), Arel.sql('DATE'))
  ])
)
```